# non-Archimedean normed space

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, banach-spaces, nonarchimedian-analysis

**Definition** Let $(F,|\cdot|)$ be a field equipped with an absolute value. A *normed vector space* over $F$ is a pair $(V,\|\cdot\|)$ consisting of an $F$-vector space $V$ and a map $\|\cdot\| : V → \mathbb{R}$ satisfying

- $\|v\|\geq 0$ with equality if and only if $v = 0$,
- $\|cv\| = |c|\cdot\|v\|$ for all $c\in F$ and $v\in V$,
- $\|v + w\| \leq \|v\| + \|w\|$ for all $v,w \in V$.

How to prove that if $F$ is non-archimedean then there is a constant $C > 0$ (depending on the normed vector space) such that $\|v+w\| \leq C\max(\|v\|,\|w\|)$ for all $v,w \in V$.

Comment: If $C$ actually depends on the normed vector space, then with direct sum we could get an infinite-dimensional example of a normed space where it fails.  So try to find $C$ that does not depend on the space.

Comment: Is there any missing upper bound for $C$ in your question? Any norm will satisfy the inequality for $C=2$ independently of the absolute value of $F$.